# Question on consequences of a very large loop

Tags: c#, loops

When looping through a very large language (say in C# 1.0), which is, for example, 5,000,000 loop iterations, what problems may this cause (performance/GC etc). This is only for the loop body.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are wanting to do?

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't make sense. Do you mean a loop with a body that allocates a lot of memory or do you mean a loop with many iterations? Can you give a code example of where you think might be a problem? Do you *actually have a problem* or is this just *speculation*?

Comment: Sorry, a loop with many iterations. This was just a brainteaser-type question I was asked.

Comment: Your answer of course should have been: "yes, C# is a large language.  Not sure how I would loop through it."  Questioning the questioner is an important part of gaining some resemblance of  control over the interview process.  If a question doesn't make sense to you, assume that it was a dumb question.  If it wasn't, you won't get the job anyway.  The exact same rules apply after you get the job.  Not questioning confuzzling requirements is recipe for project disaster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method does nothing 5,000,000 times:

```
public static void TestTest()
{            
  for(int i = 0; i != 5000000; ++i);
}
```

Compiling produces the following IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static void TestTest() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 num)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0001: stloc.0 
    L_0002: br.s L_0008
    L_0004: ldloc.0 
    L_0005: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0006: add 
    L_0007: stloc.0 
    L_0008: ldloc.0 
    L_0009: ldc.i4 0x4c4b40
    L_000e: bne.un.s L_0004
    L_0010: ret 
}
```

Running on a Pentium, I find it's JITted to:

```
00000000  push        ebp  
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        eax  
00000004  cmp         dword ptr ds:[002030E4h],0 
0000000b  je          00000012 
0000000d  call        6CE7A839 
00000012  xor         edx,edx 
00000014  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],edx 
00000017  xor         edx,edx 
00000019  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],edx 
0000001c  nop              
0000001d  jmp         00000022 
0000001f  inc         dword ptr [ebp-4] 
00000022  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-4],4C4B40h 
00000029  jne         0000001F 
0000002b  nop              
0000002c  mov         esp,ebp 
0000002e  pop         ebp  
0000002f  ret
```

Mostly this just spends its time incrementing the value, comparing it with 5000000 and then jumping a few bytes back if it isn't equal. Most likely all of this will be in the L1 cache. It could perhaps be a bit more efficient than this if hand-coded assembly, though of course the real way that it should be optimised is to ignore the whole thing, but barring that this is pretty much as good as you could expect with any language.

All in all, it's neither the size of the language, nor the loop itself that matter.

Comment: +1 for providing the "real" code being executed. I'm intrigued that the compiler doesn't just ignore the whole thing, although I guess in an incredibly obscure (and foolish) case, a loop like that could be inserted to create a pause and optimizing away would produce unintended behavior.

Comment: @Tim, yes I'm a bit disappointed that the whole thing wasn't optimised away to a null operation. On the other hand, maybe the equivalent would in other cases, I don't know myself.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone is saying, what happens in the body of the loop is the important part (and if that's your question, please post code/pseduo code).

I've written applications (mostly test drivers) which allocate, use, and dispose objects within loops that iterate millions of times. I believe the largest loop I've used was at least 15 million cycles.

The end state of the machine was the same as the start state. "Good performance" is subjective, but I was pleased with the results.

FWIW, there are processes that loop indefinitely within Windows, demonstrating that the number of iterations can be considered irrelevant in many cases. It's what happens inside the loop that counts, but modern memory allocation/disposition routines (whether manual or GC-automated) are very capable of keeping up with a sensible loop.

Of course, you could write a busy loop to purposely detract from the performance of the system, such as opening millions of handles to unmanaged objects and never disposing of those handles in .Net.

EDIT: after seeing Jon's IL/assembly, it appears that the IL compiler does not optimize away a loop, even if it's empty, so I have removed that theory.

Comment: I wouldn't remove it entirely. It's certainly a possible optimisation, and that it doesn't happen in one particular case doesn't mean it won't happen otherwise. And of course, future improvements are possible. I almost hesitate in my answer, in case I encourage over-indulgence in loop-unwinding.

Answer (score 0):

The GC operates outside of your application, when you hit a threshold it'll automatically clean up what it can. Anything defined inside the scope of the loop body and not maintained at a lower scope will be marked for finalizing/collection whenever the GC feels like it's appropriate.

Other than that, a large loop (5 million) has not Real performance issues (at least not without more information). It'll just iterate and do what it does.

Answer (score 0):

In a large loop, try to avoid allocating more objects than you need, or the garbage collector will jump in repeatedly and pause the loop. Normally the garbage collector can jump in and work when your application is waiting for something else, so it's not even noticable, but in a long loop there is no idle time that the garbage collector can take advantage of.

If you are accessing a large array in the loop, try to access it in a linear fashion. That way the data that you work with is in the memory cache most of the time. If you for example loop over a two dimensional array and have the first index as inner loop, you will be jumping back and forth in the array, causing a lot more cache misses.

And of course, using `+=` to create a string in a loop performs very badly, as you will be shuffling larger and larger strings each iterations. For example creating a 10000 character string by adding one character at a time takes 40 ms on my computer, but creating a 100000 character string doesn't take 400 ms, but 8000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers posted, you should avoid putting a long-running loop in the UI thread / main thread of a GUI app.  This doesn't matter much if you're writing a console app, but it does if you're writing a WinForms or WPF app.

Windows apps' UI responsiveness is driven by message processing, and if you get into a long-running for loop without "coming up for air" to process window messages every now and then, your UI will freeze and your user will think your app has crashed.

You can add message processing to the body of your long-running loop (Application.ProcessMessages in Delphi/C++ VCL) but that leads to new problems with reentrancy - user selecting a menu item while in your for loop leading to recursion.

Your best bet for a GUI app is to put long-running loops like this in a background thread so that your UI will remain responsive.